# how to simulate $ function when can't use jquery 

Tags: javascript, jquery

my iphone can't use jquery , so i have to simulate  $ function by myself:

this is my code :

```
function $(str){
    var div=document.createElement('div')
    div.innerHTML=str;
    return div
   }
```

and you can see , the result has a Redundant parent div，

so how to clear the raw div ,

thanks

Comment: "The $ function" basically *is* jQuery. What part of its functionality are you trying to reproduce? Also, why doesn't jQuery work on the iPhone? It should work fine.

Comment: because My boss does not agree to use jquery,  jquery is big.

Comment: I think the main question is "What part of its functionality are you trying to reproduce?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd think you could instead return `div.childNodes[0]`.

Comment: wouldn't be `div.firstChild` shorter and more efficient?

Answer (score 1):

What exact behavior(s) of $ are you trying to replicate. It does a lot:

```
$('#anid') //returns a DOM element reference if found
$('.aClass') //returns either one or more DOM element references

$('<a href="http://a.link.com">A Link</a>') // generates a DOM element and returns it

$(document) //passes a DOM reference into jQuery to be acted on

var a = document.getElementById('anid');
$(a) //passing in a DOM element reference for jQuery to act on.
```

So as you can see, $() *does a lot*. What exactly are you trying to achieve? Additionally, is this only for the iPhone or is the project you're working on expected to work on non-webkit browsers too?

Answer (score 0):

Once this function callisover

returndiv=$(str);
this.div=returndiv
document.body.appendChilde(returndiv)

this should make it work